# How to handle base url calls in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url

I have a default controller with an **index function**, which is callable with

`http://localhost/myproject/welcome`

but I also want to handle calls to the base url

`http://localhost/myproject/`

How can I do that?

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

Edit:
I´ve declared the Welcome controller as default controller

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
```

This is the htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Where is your controller name in URL ??

Comment: Localhost/projectname

Comment: When your default controller is `welcome`. Your URL looks like `http://localhost/welcome`

Comment: ok wait a second pls. I made a mistake in the post

Comment: What's your sever? Post your htaccess. You want base url to hit the index of your default controller without specifying...server configuration or your CI config file.

Comment: what happen if you access like this `http://localhost/myproject/`

Comment: I´m getting a 404 - page not found

Comment: Simple tip in your route 404 part add `welcome` ;) `$route['404_override'] = 'welcome';`

Comment: add your `base_url` too

Comment: Make sure you have set your base_url to `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myproject/';`

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you want to remove `index` from your URL, I suggest you first set your `.htaccess` to do just that:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Second step:

Check CI's `config.php` and set `$config['base_url']` to where ever your `index.php` file is located ( You said you wanted `http://localhost/myproject/`. Do not leave off the trailing backslash.)

Set your`config['index_page']` value to `''` (empty)

You've alreaday set your default controller, you should be good  to go.

Comment: thank you, this solves my problem, but creates a new one. all sub pages are now redirected to http://localhost/subpage...the project segment is missing in between. If I delete RewriteBase /, it works again